# Java WebView generate an exception on Windows XP

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, webview

This is my first question here, so I hope to be clear.
I am developing a simple JavaFX Application, the only thing it has to do is showing a web user interface.
Everything seems to be ok, I exported the Runnable JAR File from Eclipse and I tested it on Window 10 and 7, but when I put the jar on Window XP OS, I have the following:

> ```
>     Exception in Application start method
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
> der.java:58)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherIm
> pl.java:917)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(
> LauncherImpl.java:182)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Invalid URL for class: rsrc:com/sun/g
> lass/utils/NativeLibLoader.class
>         at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoad
> er.java:162)
>         at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoad
> er.java:94)
>         at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:
> 39)
>         at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.lambda$static$39(WebPage.java:130)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at com.sun.webkit.WebPage.<clinit>(WebPage.java:129)
>         at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:879)
>         at javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.<init>(WebEngine.java:866)
>         at javafx.scene.web.WebView.<init>(WebView.java:273)
>         at application.Main.start(Main.java:30)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162
> (LauncherImpl.java:863)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(Platfor
> mImpl.java:326)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.
> java:295)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformI
> mpl.java:294)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatch
> er.java:95)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>         at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.ja
> va:191)
>         ... 1 more
> ```

Here is my code:

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.Alert.AlertType;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        stage.setMinWidth( 800 );
        stage.setMinHeight( 600 );
        stage.setMaximized( true );
        Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());

        WebView browser = new WebView();
        WebEngine we = browser.getEngine();

        //setting personalized context menu
        browser.setContextMenuEnabled( false );
        //createContextMenu( browser );

        //preventing bug when maximmizing
        stage.maximizedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> ov, Boolean t, Boolean t1 )
            {
                System.out.println("maximized:" + t1.booleanValue());
            }
        });

        //intercepting javascript alert
        browser.getEngine().setOnAlert( new EventHandler<WebEvent<String>>()
        {

            @Override
            public void handle(WebEvent<String> e)
            {
                Alert alert = new Alert( AlertType.WARNING );
                alert.setTitle( "MyApp" );
                alert.setHeaderText( null );
                alert.setContentText( e.getData() );
                alert.showAndWait();
                System.out.println("JS alert() message: " + e.getData() );
            }

        });

        //intercepting javascript confirm
        browser.getEngine().setConfirmHandler( new Callback<String, Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public Boolean call( String s )
            {
                Boolean ret;
                ButtonType ok, cancel;

                ok = new ButtonType( "Ok" );
                cancel = new ButtonType( "Abort" );

                Alert alert = new Alert( AlertType.CONFIRMATION );
                alert.setTitle( "SameLAB" );
                alert.setHeaderText( s );
                alert.setContentText( null );
                alert.getButtonTypes().setAll( ok, cancel );
                alert.showAndWait();

                if( alert.getResult() == ok )
                    ret = true;
                else
                    ret = false;

                return ret;
            }
        });


        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane();
        sp.setFitToWidth( true );
        sp.setFitToHeight( true );
        sp.setContent(browser);

        //loading and showing content
        we.load("https://www.google.it/");
        scene.setRoot( sp );
        stage.setScene( scene );
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Hope that someone cal help me, thank you!

Comment: Which version of Java is installed on the WinXP box?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2283029

Comment: @JimGarrison on WinXP machine I upgraded Java to the last version release: 1.8.0_121 and of course I produced the jar file with a relative JRE (1.8.0_121 32bit)

Comment: @GKR thank you, I will keep an eye on this!

Comment: Windows XP is not a supported platform for Java. (In fact, Windows XP is no longer supported by Microsoft either.)

Comment: I know that WXP is not supported anymore, but people I work for have three devices with that OS, and no mood to upgrade for their problems. So have I to consider to switch back to SWT with Browser component? I hoped there was a way for WebView to work in W XP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered this issue today after upgrading to the last JDK 121.
The same problem is with early release JDK 122.

As for now WebView and HTMLEditor works fine when using JDK 77 (probably some later versions too (as stated in the link below - 102), but i didn't check out for it).
Problem is with loading library NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary("jfxwebkit");
There were some vague suggestions that some new Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributables may help.

Edited.
It's already in bugreport: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8170084 and, alas, closed with the Resolution: "Won't Fix".

So, one option is left - provide bundled JRE version 1.8.0_102 or less for Windows XP.

Comment: Thans a lot RoK, I'll try your solution. Maybe it will result a little unuseful just because I think that WebView in W XP will use Internet Explorer 8, so no bootstrap support and no jquery support too, I'll see, but thanks for your help :)

Comment: Sorry, Matt Chad, I messed up with JDK versions in my project and second workaround with System.load doesn't work actualy. Only first with bundled JRE. I recommend Launch4j wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

So, one option is left - provide bundled JRE version 1.8.0_102 or less for Windows XP. Another temporary dirty option: bundle your application with jfxwebkit.dll from 1.8.0_102 and add somewhere in your code before WebView instance created (for example, in start(Stage primaryStage) method)

```
if ("Windows XP".equals(System.getProperty("os.name"))){ 
System.load(ABS_PATH_TO_JFXWEBKIT_DLL + "\\jfxwebkit.dll");}
```

Comment: Will try! Thank you! :)